# Iterate and update through folder of .json files and update value in python

Tags: python, json, loops

I've struck out trying to find a suitable script to iterate through a folder of .json files and update a single line.

Below is an example json file located in a path among others. I would like to iterate through the json files in a folder containing several files like this with various information and update the "seller_fee_basis_points" from "0" to say "500" and save.

Would really appreciate the assistance.

```
{
  "name": "Solflare X NFT",
  "symbol": "",
  "description": "Celebratory Solflare NFT for the Solflare X launch",
  "seller_fee_basis_points": 0,
  "image": "https://www.arweave.net/abcd5678?ext=png",
  "animation_url": "https://www.arweave.net/efgh1234?ext=mp4",
  "external_url": "https://solflare.com",
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "web",
      "value": "yes"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "mobile",
      "value": "yes"
   },
   {
      "trait_type": "extension",
      "value": "yes"
    }
  ],
  "collection": {
     "name": "Solflare X NFT",
     "family": "Solflare"
  },
  "properties": {
    "files": [
      {
        "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/abcd5678?ext=png",
        "type": "image/png"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://watch.videodelivery.net/9876jkl",
        "type": "unknown",
        "cdn": true
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://www.arweave.net/efgh1234?ext=mp4",
        "type": "video/mp4"
      }
    ],
    "category": "video",
    "creators": [
      {
        "address": "SOLFLR15asd9d21325bsadythp547912501b",
        "share": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Updated with an answer due to @JCaesar's help

```
import json
import glob
import os

SOURCE_DIRECTORY = r'my_favourite_directory'
KEY = 'seller_fee_basis_points'
NEW_VALUE = 500

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, '*.json')):
    json_data = json.loads(open(file, encoding="utf8").read())
    # note that using the update method means
    # that if KEY does not exist then it will be created
    # which may not be what you want
    json_data.update({KEY: NEW_VALUE})
    json.dump(json_data, open(file, 'w'), indent=4)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: Will you be wanting to update that key to the same value for all files?

Comment: What part are you stuck on? Iterating over all files in a folder, or changing a value in a JSON file. (Note: there are no "lines" in JSON lines.)

Comment: Using a bit of bash, jq and sed would be one (quicker) way to do this, but you definitely tagged this python.

Comment: @JCaesar yes I'd like to edit the key to the same value for all.

Comment: @9769953 Changing and overwriting a json is my key issue, have no experience with those other options unfortunately but would appreciate direction to some documentation if it's quick to pick up for this use case

Comment: Thanks for the question bro helped me out with my NFT collection xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using *glob* to find the files you're interested in. Then utilise the *json* module for reading and writing the JSON content.

This is very concise and has no sanity checking / exception handling but you should get the idea:

```
import json
import glob
import os

SOURCE_DIRECTORY = 'my_favourite_directory'
KEY = 'seller_fee_basis_points'
NEW_VALUE = 500

for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, '*.json')):
    json_data = json.loads(open(file).read())
    # note that using the update method means
    # that if KEY does not exist then it will be created
    # which may not be what you want
    json_data.update({KEY: NEW_VALUE})
    json.dump(json_data, open(file, 'w'), indent=4)
```